# Unity Facebook Publish_actions Review don't Answer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, publish-actions

I need publish_actions permission to use Facebook Score API as you know, 
but when send my mobile app to Facebook Review, they said your facebook account blocked for 72 hours (everytime facebook account blocked min. 7 days and i cant login) ,
Then 7- 10 days facebook account open but i look my developer console, nothing changed and there isn't mail in my e-mail or notification??? 
Is there a bug ?? Or facebook doesnt like me ? 
I try to take permission every week. I need only this permission to publish my app on stores.

Thanks for supports,

Answer (score 0):

I use my old facebook account to review and problem was solved.
I tried with new accounts, they blocked for security